# Problem installing pg gem properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, postgresql, amazon-ec2, pg

I have a rails app that I am trying to get running in an Amazon EC2 instance. This app has been tested properly on various Linux, OS X and Windows systems.

On the EC2 server, I have built PostgresSQL 9 from source. At first, the 'pg' gem wouldn't install but I built it with the following command:

```
gem install pg -- --with-pgsql-lib=/usr/local/pgsql/lib --with-pgsql-config=/usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_config
```

This seemed to build properly. However, when I run a rake task, such as 'rake db:migrate' I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/pg-0.11.0/lib/pg_ext.so
```

Comment: Have you installed the development files for Postgres?. When building a driver these files are required in order to build correctly.

Comment: Should you have used `rvm` to install the gem, rather than the `gem` tool?

Comment: Yes. I am using RVM. Also, see the output of a find command: sudo find / -name libpq.so.5 -ls
153069    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 postgres postgres       12 Jun 10 04:46 /usr/local/pgsql/lib/libpq.so.5 -> libpq.so.5.3

Comment: FWIW, I finally got around to installing RVM on my single EC2 (c1.medium instance) Rails (2.x, passenger, Apache) app last month. Over the weekend - with lower than normal usage - the server load was over double the normal (weekday) load, so I had to remove RVM immediately. You'll want to test performance before you put that into production. The EC2 stack is slow enough already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the error message and your description of your 'find' command output, it's possible that `/usr/local/pgsql/lib` is not in the path the dynamic linker searches for its libraries. Try adding that directory to `/etc/ld.so.conf` (or similar), or set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include it before you run `rake`.

Comment: That is a useful tip and something I didn't know. Thank you.

Comment: I had to use ld.so.conf to do this.  Setting LIBPATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH didn't work for me on Ubuntu for some reason.

Answer (score 8):

Did the trick for me on EC2 for pg gem:

```
sudo yum install postgresql-devel
```

Answer (score 2):

Weird. I backed out RVM completely and re-did everything exactly the same way but this time with the ARCHFLAGS set. It occurred to me that I had forgot to set it.

```
env ARCHFLAGS=" -arch x86_64"
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned whether this succeeded or not. You should only need to specify the architecture on platforms like MacOS X which have a Ruby compiled with more than one architecture.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could solve this was by adding a symlink so it could find it.

```
ln -s /usr/pgsql-9.2/lib/libpq.so.5.5 /usr/lib/libpq.so.5
```